# Compact Python for() Loop

Tags: python

How do I rearrange the following code into a simplified list comprehension?

```
for i in xrange(len(list)):
    if list[i].startswith('c'):
        list[i] = prefix + list[i]
```

I tried the following but it did not seem to work:

```
[prefix + list[i] for i in xrange(len(list)) if list[i].startswith('c')]
```

The following throws me off:

```
list[i] = prefix + list[i]
```

Comment: Note that this is called a [list comprehension](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use the [`ternary operator`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) here:

```
[prefix + i if i.startswith('c') else i for i in my_list]
```

Note that this doesn't changes the original `my_list`, it simply returns a new list.

You can simply asssign the list comprehension back to `my_list` to achieve that:

```
my_list=[prefix + i if i.startswith('c') else i for i in my_list]
```

PS: Don't use `list` as a variable name

Comment: I see now that the xrange was not necessary. Thanks for the warning of using 'list' as a variable name.